# What header should I use to send a video to the backend with the rtk query?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Is it necessary to set the header manually to send the video / file to the backend in the rtk query mutation?
One day I set it manually, I got the answer, but one day I did not set it. What is the best way to do it? Is this a problem with large files?